# Generic number literals

Tags: d

```d
bool isUnit(Vec)(in Vec v, float tolerance = kindaSmallNumber){
    import std.math: abs;
    import std.conv: to;
    auto length = v.lengthSquared;
    return abs(to!(typeof(length))(1) - length) < tolerance;
}
```

Here I just want to calculate `1 - length` but length could be of type double or float. I don't want to convert 1 from integer to `float` or `double` at runtime.

Do I have to do `to!(typeof(length))(1) - length` or can I just do `1 - length` and `1` will always be of the same type as length?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of 1 is irrelevant there. It will be automatically converted to an appropriate type for arithmetic with length.

From http://dlang.org/spec/expression.html#AddExpression

> If either operand is a floating point type, the other is implicitly converted to floating point and they are brought to a common type via the usual arithmetic conversions.

So it is done automatically anyway by the compiler (which btw is known at compile time, of course, so it doesn't do any runtime stuff here).

But for other people who want to know the answer to the specific question, you could use typed literals like `1.0` or a type constructor, like `typeof(length)(1)`.